# How to read data from fields in MS Word?

Tags: vb.net

Using vb.net and Word 2010

```
Dim oWord As msword.Application    
Dim oDoc As msword.Document
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(TextBox1.Text)
MsgBox(oWord.ActiveDocument.Fields(1))
```

Opening the document is not a problem. Reading the value of the field is causing errors, like `Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'`.
I've tried naming the field in quotes, that doesn't work either. I've tried `Variable.field(1)` - that gets me an error as well

Help appreciated!

Comment: What is a field in the context of your question? Is it a range or bookmark or some other value? When I get stuck with Word automation, I record a macro mimicking the behavior I want, and then inspect the code that way.

Comment: This works but will not give me  a value from the field For i = 1 To oWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Count - 1
            MsgBox("Type: " &
            oWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Item(i).Type.ToString)
            MsgBox("Result.Text: " &
            oWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Item(i).Result.Text())

            MsgBox("Value: " &
            oWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Item(i).Result..Text())
        Next
        oWord.Quit()